# Java EE 6 security - use user entity class

Tags: security, java-ee-6, jaspic

All I need is a simple login page that will check against the username and password of a simple User entity class.
Is that possible with Java EE 6? In the tutorials they always store the users on the glassfish server.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Java EE 6 with the JASPIC API. However, this is currently [a somewhat lower-level API](http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.com/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html) and actually implementing a simple login on basis of an application provided entity is thus still not that simple.

I've created a JIRA issue that addresses this specific requirement and provided a prototype implementation. See [JAVAEE_SPEC-9](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAEE_SPEC-9) for more information.

Comment: Great article http://arjan-tijms.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html, Thanks!

Comment: @Michael Glad you liked it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you need is form based authentication and Java EE provides some support for it. More details at the below link [login authentication](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html)